# How to have autocompletebox grow large upon item selected

Tags: xaml, xamarin

I'm currently using syncfusion's autocomplete, the mode is set to Token which allows me to select multiple items. As I select more items from my autocomplete, they don't appear once I have multiple selected. I'm wondering how can I get the autocompletebox's height to grow automatically.

I've set the MinimumHeightRequest to 60 and I set vertical options to EndAndExpand and it still doesn't grow, cuts off previously selecteditems.

With 1 item selected

[image]

With 2 items selected

[image]

With 3 items selected

[image]

The behaviour i'm looking for is that the height will grow to accommodate the selected items.

```
<autocomplete:SfAutoComplete x:Name="autoComplete"
                                DisplayMemberPath="Location"
                                MultiSelectMode="Token"
                                MinimumHeightRequest="60"
                                VerticalOptions="EndAndExpand"
                                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                                TokensWrapMode="Wrap" 
                                ItemPadding="20,10,0,0"
                                IsSelectedItemsVisibleInDropDown="false"
                                Watermark="Search for Location"
                                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLocation}"
                                DataSource="{Binding FilteredLocations}"                                                   
                                Text="{Binding SearchLocation, Mode=TwoWay}" >      
</autocomplete:SfAutoComplete>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by nesting `Grid` in the outer layer like this :

```
<Grid Grid.Row="1"
          Margin="10,0,10,0">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

        <autocomplete:SfAutoComplete>
            ......
        </autocomplete:SfAutoComplete>
</Grid>
```

You can refer to this ：https://blog.syncfusion.com/post/overview-of-the-autocomplete-control-in-xamarin-forms.aspx